# Is React context provider not mounted before child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I make sure I set a value in the context provider before components are mounted?

In the code example below, the console.log in the child component(Dashboard) will be logged first (as undefined). Why is that and is there any way for me to make sure the value is set before that component is mounted?

**App.js**

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <ContextProvider>
        <Dashboard />
      </ContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**ContextProvider.js**

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.setState({value: 1})
  console.log(this.state.value);
}
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  console.log(this.context.value);
}
```

Comment: This isn't specific to context provider. You would get the same behaviour from any parent/child relationship.

Comment: @estus Thanks for the fast response. So the childs componentDidMount function is always called before the parents? In my case I want to grab the market based on the url in the global state (context) to be used by all components. Do you have any idéa how you could do that? I just realized a work-around for now, that is, I'm actually grabbing the market from the url in each component that needs it. Feels very unnecessary though.

Comment: Yes, it is. Especially since the value you expect is set asynchronously after a component is mounted. setState is async. The thing you describe is what context is for.

Answer (score 3):

Children are rendered first. Regardless of that, `setState` is asynchronous, so a context will be provided to consumers asynchronously.

In case there's a necessity for children to wait for a context, they should be either conditionally rendered:

```
render() {
  this.context.value && ...
}
```

Or be wrapped with context consumer which can be written as a HOC for reuse:

```
const withFoo = Comp => props => (
  <FooContext.Consumer>{foo => foo.value && <Comp {...props}/>}</FooContext.Consumer>
);
```